# onclick jquery menu not working after ajax

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

having trouble with some jquery & ajax. basically user logins in via form which is ajax. the form is in a jquery onclick dropdown menu which is also used for shopping cart menu (just changed naming code (css+jquery) so dont conflict with each other, and  both are working as should until user logs in (via ajax)).

here is the jquery code below

```
//////Cart App
jQuery(".dropdown-cart dt a").click(function() {
        // Change the behaviour of onclick states for links within the menu.
    var toggleId = "#" + this.id.replace(/^link/,"ul");

        // Hides all other menus depending on JQuery id assigned to them
    jQuery(".dropdown-cart dd ul").not(toggleId).hide();

        //Only toggles the menu we want since the menu could be showing and we want to hide it.
    jQuery(toggleId).toggle();

        //Change the css class on the menu header to show the selected class.
    if(jQuery(toggleId).css("display") == "none"){
        jQuery(this).removeClass("selected");
    }else{
        jQuery(this).addClass("selected");
    }
});

jQuery(".dropdown-cart dd ul li a").click(function() {

    // This is the default behaviour for all links within the menus
    var text = jQuery(this).html();
    jQuery(".dropdown-cart dt a span").html(text);
    jQuery(".dropdown-cart dd ul").hide();

});

jQuery(document).bind('click', function(e) {

    // Lets hide the menu when the page is clicked anywhere but the menu.
    var $clicked = jQuery(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown-cart")){
        jQuery(".dropdown-cart dd ul").hide();
            jQuery(".dropdown-cart dt a").removeClass("selected");
        }

});
```

i have tried a few .live combos, even .delgate but still after user logs in both logged in & cart onclick menus dont work until page is refreshed

any ideas??

cheers
nz warrior

Comment: what jquery version you have ?

Comment: is your code in ready ??

Comment: We are guessing somewhat until you show us your ajax code.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are updating the anchor tags once user logged in via ajax. so your event bindings ( click event) you registered earlier is lost. You should use jQuery [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for binding instead of click

This code

```
jQuery(".dropdown-cart dt a").click(function() {
     //remaining code   
});
```

should change to

```
$(document).on("click",".dropdown-cart dt a",function() {
    //remaining code   
});
```

jquery `on` works for current elements and future elements and is available from jQuery 1.7+ versions.

Answer (score 0):

try this

wrap the code into a `function` and call that function in your html tag using `onclick` event

```
onclick='function_name(this)' --> in your html tag

function function_name(element){
   //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
$(".dropdown-cart dt a").click(function(){})
```

With:

jQuery 1.7+

```
$(".dropdown-cart").on("click","dt a", function(){})
```

jQuery 1.4.3+

```
$(".dropdown-cart").delegate("dt a", "click", function(){})
```

jQuery 1.3+

```
$(".dropdown-cart dt a").live("click",function(){})
```

in that case you don't need to bind new ajax-loaded components.

Comment: use of `.delegate` is more appropriate for jquery versions earlier than the 1.7 or 1.6

Comment: yes. delegate is closer to the .on method, agree, should perform faster than .live ...